# Is it better to use a single large data file or lots of small data files — which is faster?

Tags: database

I want to make a program to keep record of students in a university and provide a search method.
Which of the following methods will be faster?

1. Make one file for each student
2. Make single data file and search?

The size of student data will be different for different student.

Comment: Opening a file is a relatively slow process.  Having large numbers of files rather than a single one is probably slower, unless you're able to access the correct file by name based on your query.  For the search code, you might find multiple files works well.  However, when it comes to listing all the students at the university, multiple files becomes a disaster (especially if the names are hashes and you need to present the data in name sorted order).  This is a game of trade-offs.  And real DBMS and data management packages are rather good at it — but have a lot of code to make it so.

Comment: If it is a homework you should tell that and you should explain on which OS, with which language, are you permitted to use additional libraries. In all cases edit your question to improve it.

Comment: The normal way to answer the question "which is faster" is to implement and test both and compare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) and [file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) specific. Some general hints (with an implicit focus on [Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux) systems, with good enough file systems like [Ext4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4), [BTRFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btrfs), etc...).

- Consider using a [database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database), perhaps just [Sqlite](http://sqlite.org/), or a DBMS like [PostGreSQL](http://postgresql.org/) or [MongoDB](http://mongodb.org/) ([indexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index) is essential for performance)
- Your question depends upon the data size. If you are sure it is small enough to easily fit in RAM (e.g. less than a hundred megabytes on a recent laptop or desktop), you could [serialize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) and deserialize all the data using some textual format like [JSON](http://json.org/). On the contrary, if you are sure that you have data-center sized data (several petabytes) things are *very* different.
- In general, avoid having many tiny files, e.g. dozen of thousands of kilobyte sized files. Prefer having fewer but bigger files (but if possible avoid *huge* file sizes, e.g. terabytes or larger than half of your biggest disk or partition; see however [LVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_%28Linux%29)).
- Perhaps an indexed file library like [GDBM](http://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/) would be worthwhile.
- If you need to have a lot of files, put them in subdirectories: so `dir01/subdir02/file0345.txt` is better than `file01020345.txt`; avoid having large directories with e.g. more than a thousand files. (See figure on wikipage about [Ext2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext2) to understand why).
- You might have a mixed approach: small contents (e.g. less than megabyte) in some database, large contents in files (with some metadata in a database). Read also about [binary large objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object) (BLOBs).
- Read also about [application checkpointing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_checkpointing) or [persistence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_%28computer_science%29)
- define, implement and *test* some [backup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backup) and some restore (human) procedures. For a (not huge) database, dump it in textual format (e.g. SQL).

<sup>So your work should start with an estimate of the size of the data, and how (and how often) is it accessed (and changed).</sup>

If it is homework and you are not allowed to use external libraries, you should organize a file into *fixed size* records (accessed randomly, e.g. with [fseek(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fseek.3.html) or [lseek(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html)) - probably coded as some [tagged union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) and care about indexing (using e.g. [hash-tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) or [B-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) techniques). You might need to manage [linked lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) of several low-level records to handle large data.

Studying the implementation of *sqlite* or of *GDBM* (both are [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), you should download and study their source code) will be inspirational.

<sup>Notice that most universities have only a few dozen thousands of students, and I guess that each student would need a few (or a dozen of) kilobytes (unless you want to store photos or videos of every student!) for identity, scores and courses information. So in practice you probably need only several dozens of megabytes (maybe two gigabytes), and that fits today in RAM.</sup>